# I want to find all the head lines containing certain word/words to be scraped and saved to a text file

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I use a list of words and make the program pull out any new headings containing any one of the words inside the list. It gives out a error if I try to use the list of key words.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s_date = '2018/01/01'
e_date = '2018/01/06'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(e_date, '%Y/%m/%d')

delta = timedelta(days = 1)

date_list =  list()
while d1 <= d2:
#    print(d1.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    date_list.append(d1.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    d1 += delta
print(date_list)

for d in date_list:
    URL = 'https://www.thedailystar.net/newspaper?date={}'.format(d)
    result = requests.get(URL)
    src = result.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
#    filename = 'new.csv'
#    f = open(filename, 'w', newline = '')
#    fx = csv.writer(f)
    containers = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'list-content')
    key_words = ['Road', 'crash', 'dead', 'accidents']
    key_word = input('Enter the desired word to search the news: ')
    for c in containers:
            headings = c.h5.a.text
            if key_word in headings:
                print(headings)
                with open('nw.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(headings)

#                    fx.writerow(headings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several bugs in your code, that's why it didn't work as expected.

Here's the correct version of what you want to achieve:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s_date = '2018/01/01'
e_date = '2018/01/06'
d1 = datetime.strptime(s_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime(e_date, '%Y/%m/%d')

delta = timedelta(days = 1)

date_list =  list()
while d1 <= d2:
    date_list.append(d1.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    d1 += delta
print(date_list)

with open('nw.txt', 'w') as f:
    for d in date_list:
        URL = 'https://www.thedailystar.net/newspaper?date={}'.format(d)
        result = requests.get(URL)
        src = result.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
        containers = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'list-content')
        key_words = ['Road', 'crash', 'dead', 'accidents']
    #    key_word = input('Enter the desired word to search the news: ')
        
        for c in containers:
            headings = c.h5.a.text
            if any(key_word in headings for key_word in key_words):
                print(headings)
                f.write(headings + '\n')
```

**What's happening** (changes are at the bottom):

If you wanted to use a list of keywords (which is called `key_words`), then an option is to use built-in `any` function and iterate over all of keywords, checking wherther it is `in` your current `headings`.

Also you're `open`-ing file every time you want to write - it destroys last write and creates a new file. Instead you should `open` file once before loop.

Plus when you were writing `headings` to file, you didn't add `\n` which is the newline symbol - it would cause all headings to append as one row.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am a beginner and I've learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: @SilviaIslamEera, no problem, glad to help=)